# Powershell MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, powershell, ssh

Two servers, one on Windows server + WAMP, one on Linux Debian + MySQL
I would like to understand why I don't get the same result from these two following ways:

- From a phpmyadmin (MySQL on linux) I import a sql file
- From MySQL (on windows server) I launch this powershell

Script file content:

```
$mysqlpath = "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\"
$username = xxx
$password = xxx
$backuppath = "C:\"
$backupfile = $backuppath + "file.sql" 
CD $mysqlpath
&cmd /c "mysql -u $username -p$password -h 0.0.0.0 < $backupfile" 
CD C:\
```

NOTE: (0.0.0.0 is Linux server IP address)

- Why i don t get the same result from these two ways?
- How can I set up the powershell file with the right parameters to get the same results that the first solution ?
- In using WinRM and ssh, can I lauch my powershell file on windows to execute via ssh the mysql command on linux server ?

Comment: In what way do your results differ? You've provided no information that can be used to understand what's being output. How do you know that it's PowerShell changing the results and not a difference between Linux & Windows MySQL binaries? What happens if you run the query on Windows independent of PowerShell?